# how to update process.version in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pm2

I have recently upgraded my node version from v3 to v11 using nvm.
nvm use 11.12.0

So, now when i do **node -v** in terminal, it gives output as:-
11.12.0

Now I have node js application which we start through **pm2**. I have even updated the interpreter to 11.12.0 using **--interpreter option** provided by pm2.

When i do **pm2 info**, the interpreter option is correctly pointing to v11.12.0 but node version is pointing to v3.

Even, **process.version** in my application code is pointing to v3.

How do i run my application using v11 so that **process.version** will return 11.12.0 not v3

Comment: Add nodejs path from the one in nvm before in PATH variable. Alternatively you can just uninstall the previous nodejs install

Comment: how to add that path through pm2. CAn you please help  me with some command line code?

Comment: having the same problem, if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating my node installation with npm.

```
npm i node@12.18.2 -g
```

The process.version was updated.